# How to override properties of java classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, java-interop

Somewhere in Java code there is a class `ViewHolder`:

```
public static abstract class ViewHolder {
    public final View itemView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) { this.itemView = itemView; }
    ....
}
```

So in Kotlin instances of this class contain a read-only property `itemView` of type `View`. And I want to create a generic class `ViewHolder<V>` like this:

```
class MyViewHolder<V : View>(itemView: V) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
     override val itemView = super.itemView as V // error: itemView overrides nothing
}
```

And if I remove the `override` modifier the class compiles OK, but when I try to use the `itemView` field I get the `Overload resolution ambiguity` error.

What I want here is to make the `itemView` property of `MyViewHolder` class to be of type `V`, not `View`. So for instance, `MyViewHolder(TextView(context)).itemView` would be a `TextView`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java class in your example has a field, not a property. Code that accesses a field in Java always refers to a specific class name, and it's not possible to override the field in another class, either in Java or in Kotlin.

You can create your own property, with a different name, that would return the value of the field cast to the type that you need.